# Unsure if $f(x)\to \pm \infty$ for $x$ tending to the endpoints when it is strictly decreasing between them

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that a continious function $f$ is strictly decreasing on an interval $(a,b)$. When I wrote in a text, "Since $f$ is decreasing on this interval, we have that $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to a^{+}$ and $f(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to b^{-}$" my teacher says "Reason not completely clear" to this part. Could anyone explain what I'm missing here? I could have asked my teacher, but this comment was over one year ago.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks for an counterexample. Which conditions should I add to support my claim?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Sorry. Allow me explain the whole context. What if we had a continuous function $f$ that is defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_1,x_2,\dots, x_m\}$, where $x_i$'s is strictly increasing, and $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(x_1,x_2)$, $(x_2,x_3)$, ... etc, can't we still conclude that $f(x)\to \pm \infty$ as $x\to x_i^{\pm}$?

Comment: @Hopeless no, you can't conclude that.

Comment: @Randall Okay ... The reason why I asked is to see if $f$ alters its sign in $(a,b)$, so that I could use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that $f$ has exactly one root there - which is what I wanted to prove the main claim. But, the way I prove, is wrong, and I do not know what else I could improve ...

Comment: I have deleted my previous comments since they were made assuming the domain of the function is $\Bbb R$. While continuous functions with the properties you claim do exist, for example $-\arctan x$, every continuous function does not behave in this manner.

Comment: If you are struggling with a question you can make a new post asking it.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly decreasing does not necessarily mean $f(x)$ goes to $\pm \infty$ at either endpoint.  Consider $f(x) = -x$.  Then $f$ is strictly decreasing on **every** interval $(a,b)$, but so long as $a,b$ are finite we do not have that $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to a^{+}$ or $f(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to b^{-}$ on **any** such interval.